# Language to regular expression to prove it is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm trying to find a regular expression to describe the following language:

$\{a^n xa^n | n≥1,x ∈ Σ^* \}$

where $Σ$ = {a,b}

So far I've come up with

$aa^* (aUb)^* aa^*$

but I don't think that accounts for $n$ being the same.

Comment: Hint: consider word in the language of the form $a^n x a^n$ for some $n \ge 2$ and $x \in \Sigma^*$. Is it also a word of the form $a^n x a ^n$ for $n=1$ and $x \in \Sigma^*$ (not necessarily the same $x$)?

Comment: Your regular expression can be simplified $aa^* (a \cup b)^* a a^* = aa^* (a \cup b)^* a^* a = a (a \cup b)^* a$.

Comment: side question: also trying to find an NFA, i understand that i can't fix `k` but can i fix `u`? so Let u=a?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what $k$ and $u$ are.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, too many variables floating around in my head! I meant I can't fix $n$ but can i fix $x$? so $Let x=a$?

Comment: You can't fix $x$ in the definition of the language. You can exhibit a specific choice of $n$ and $x$ if you are just trying to show that some word $w$ can be written as $a^n x a^n$ and hence $w$ is in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your language consists of all words that start with $a$ and end with a different $a$, which yields the regular expression $a(a+b)^\ast a$. Note that every word that at first seems *unbalanced*, e.g. $a^n y a^{n+k}$ for some $y \in \Sigma^\ast$ and $k > 0$ (analogously too many $a$ on the left) can be regrouped to $a^n (ya^k) a^n$ or $a (a^{n-1} y a^{n-1+k}) a$, the middle part in parenthesis being always a suitable choice for your infix $x \in \Sigma^\ast$ in the definition of your language.

Comment: thank you, why $+$ and not $aUb$?

Comment: also N has to be >=1, so if n=2, that doesn't seem to fit in the second part as the word would need to end in aa?

Comment: $a+b$ and $a \cup b$ denote the same thing (either $a$ or $b$) in this context. $n$ is not fixed. You language is is the set of $w$ all words such that **there exists** a choice of $x \in \Sigma^*$ and an integer $n \ge 1$ such that $w = a^n x a^n$. This is equivalent to the following condition: there exists a choice of $x \in \Sigma^*$ such that $w = a x a$, as the answer argues. Taking it one step further: the language is exactly $\{a\} \circ \Sigma^* \circ \{a\}$, where $\circ$ dentoes concatenation, hence the regular expression $a (a \cup b)^* a$.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that your language is not a regular language, so you are not going to find a regular expression, whatever you try. Neither is anyone else.

To see very easily that it is not regular: A regular language has a finite state machine. Now take the strings a^n b for every possible integer n. What is the shortest string to add to create a string from your language? Obviously you have to add a^n to get a^n b a^n which is in the language. Since there are infinitely many different answers, your state machine has infinitely many different states.

(In general, the rule is: For every prefix w, calculate the set of suffixes x such that wx is in the language L. If the number of different suffix sets is finite, then your language is regular, otherwise it isn't. I looked at "the shortest string in each suffix set" instead. If there are infinitely many different such shortest strings, then there are infinitely many suffix sets, so the language is irregular as well. )

PS. I read your "x" as a single symbol. Instead it is any sequence of symbols. Which makes your question a trick question, because every single sentence of at least two characters starting and ending in a belongs to the language. Say you have a^20 x a^19 - just take n = 1, and the *string* x is a^19 x a^18. The "n ≥ 1" is irrelevant. So a regular expression is trivial:

```
a (a|b)* a
```